# SEQUENTIAL bidirectional P2P with NFC on Gingerbread

Tags: android, nfc

I have the following scenario

1. Phone A prepares an NDEF message and Phone B registers foreground
   dispatch.
2. Phone A pushes the NDEF. Phone B receives this and processes it.
3. Phone A now registers for foreground dispatch and disables NDEF
   push.Phone B replies with an NDEF push.

ALL this is to be done in one swipe. How can I do this?
Right now, I have to pull the devices away for the 2nd part to work. I
have seen the sample on p2p exchange, but in that case, both the
message contents are known in advance. Here, the reply depends on the
request.

Secondly, will there be a proper NFC API with the ability to create
LLCP sockets?

Cheers,
Earlence